# Как в Go преобразовать строку в слайс?

Tags: строки, golang, динамические-массивы, append

Как в Go преобразовать строку в слайс?
Например, из строки "Hello", сделать слайс ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

У меня был такой вариант:

```
s := ""
var sl []string
for _, arg := range s {
    sl = append(sl, arg)
}
```

Компилятор ругается: "невозможно использовать тип int32 как тип string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

```
s := "hello"
ss := strings.Split(s, "")
fmt.Println(ss)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ddAuWSXEKa8

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу выше. Давайте начнём с вашего кодa:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "Hello"

    var sl []string
    for _, c := range s {
        // range разбивает на юникод символы и выдаёт int32
        // что нам нужно преобразовать в string
        // fmt.Printf("%T\n", c) // подскажет тип
        sl = append(sl, fmt.Sprintf("%c", c))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sl) // []string{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
    // работает

    // мы также можем преобразовать в массив байт и пройтись по индивидульным байтам
    sl = []string{} // пустой слайс
    for _, b := range []byte(s) {
        sl = append(sl, fmt.Sprintf("%c", b))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sl) // []string{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"}
    // "вроде" всё работает

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // но ... добавим кирилицу и скажем персидский и армянский (спросим у гугла)
    s = "Привет سلام Բարեւ"

    // начнём варианта от @Ainar-G
    sl = strings.Split(s, "")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sl) // []string{"П", "р", "и", "в", "е", "т", " ", "س", "ل", "ا", "م", " ", "Բ", "ա", "ր", "ե", "ւ"}
    // всё работает

    // ваш код
    sl = []string{} // пустой слайс
    for _, c := range s {
        sl = append(sl, fmt.Sprintf("%c", c))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sl) // []string{"П", "р", "и", "в", "е", "т", " ", "س", "ل", "ا", "م", " ", "Բ", "ա", "ր", "ե", "ւ"}
    // всё работает

    // неверный! вариант c преобразованием в массив байт который работал выше
    sl = []string{} // пустой слайс
    for _, b := range []byte(s) {
        sl = append(sl, fmt.Sprintf("%c", b))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", sl) // и .........  получаем полную ерунду
    // []string{"Ð", "\u009f", "Ñ", "\u0080", "Ð", "¸", "Ð", "²", "Ð", "µ", "Ñ", "\u0082", " ", "Ø", "³", "Ù", "\u0084", "Ø", "§", "Ù", "\u0085", " ", "Ô", "²", "Õ", "¡", "Ö", "\u0080", "Õ", "¥", "Ö", "\u0082"}
}
```

Мой последний вариант наивно "думает" что каждый символ = один байт. Код Go  всегда в кодировке utf8, что означает число байт на один юникод символ варьирует.

https://play.golang.org/p/NxVbLBKZTsY

Мудрость здесь https://blog.golang.org/strings

Вам так-же [поможет](https://github.com/Konstantin8105/Effective_Go_RU/blob/bb4dfcbd4beae11636501b68dd90ec537ab85301/README.md#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-for).

Удачи!